Storing point cloud data from a repeat zone
So here's a programming question that takes me into the advanced areas. I'm generating multiple sets of points from a Mesh to Points over several Grid objects. I'd like to use a Repeat Zone but am not sure how to store a whole array of point data within the Repeat Zone to use outside of it. Right now, this is what I have:

Where each point set goes to a 2x2 geometry generator, and the majority of points end up in Set 4, which is just 1x1 cubes. This can be seen in the picture above. (There are gaps because one of the 2x2 generators hasn't been set up yet).
What I want to do is do it this way instead:

The question is, what node would I use to store the point data from each set? "Store Named Attribute" is an obvious choice, but it doesn't index each point set automatically, and I am honestly not sure if it can store a whole array of data from a point set. Maybe storing the points by instance index instead (since the points themselves are instanced to a mesh) would work? But even that, I've no idea how to go about doing it.
Any suggestions here?

If you're going to give different uses for each set, is there a point in making a repeat zone? If each set is going to be the input of the same procedure, then you can put the entire procedure inside the repeat zone.

One alternative is to convert a set to instance, and join the instance into the repeat geometry (input geometry is empty, output geometry is join input + instanced set)
Another alternative is to store the "index of the iteration" in the points (pull an index starting at zero from the repeat zone and add 1 before connecting to the output). Use "selections" in the attribute node instead of separating geometry.

Each of the sets of points is going to an entirely different 2x2 geometry generator, with the remaining points (the inverted output) going to 1x1 cubes. So each geometry generator needs a unique set of points that do NOT overlap with the other sets, thus why I chained the Select Geometry nodes together with random values plugging in. The geometry generators aren't identical, so I can't simply stick them all in the repeat zone. Each set of points the repeat zone generates needs a unique identifier of some kind to plug into one of the four geometry generators.

Honestly, there is no point in creating a repeat zone here... Just extra work for no true benefit.

If the issue is organizing, create a "node group" and make each set have its own output socket

Thank you! You're right, I'm just trying to stretch my knowledge here. But chained Select Geometry nodes are perfectly okay and do the job. Sometimes, it doesn't matter if a solution is elegant or inelegant, long as it WORKS.

Instance collection solution
You can do it transforming each set into an instance:

Create an incremental index in the loop (you will need it to provide different seeds to the random node)
Separate the set
Transform the set into an instance
Join the instance into the "sets" collection (starts empty)
After the loop, add the remaining set

To use, you will have to separate the "instance" that has the desired index and then realize the instance.

Named attribute solution
You can also store a named attribute to each point.

Starting adding the final index to all points (they will be the only ones selected for changing the index, and will also be the remaining set)
In the loop, have the index that you will use as seed and also as the stored set attribute
Select the points among the ones that have the last index (don't want to change the other sets)
Store the new index

To use, separate the points that have the desired set index.


Thank you very much!! Yes, it's more complex than just a chain, but far more flexible and it's a good exercise to learn how repeat zones work!

@ArchibaldMirenopteryx, great. If you consider this answers your question, please click the "answered" checkmark.

Done! And thank you again!
